# I am trying to disable the breakpoint for two small buttons in bootstrap5

Tags: breakpoints, disable

I have a card, with picture, contact info and below that, I want to add two buttons, one beside the other.  The code insists on putting one on top of the other even though I have a horizontal class. There is actually room for about three of these buttons that I want to put there, but they will not go horizontal.  any advice?  Here's the code:

```
"""  <!--Info & Contact-->
<div class="container overflow-hidden">
  <div class="row gx-5 gy-5">
    <div class="col-6">
      <div class="p-3 border bg" id="pic"><img src="vickie1.png" alt="meetVickie" id="meetVickie">
      <p class="text-center">name<br>Marriage & Family Therapist M.Div. LMFT</p>

      <ul class="list-group list-group-horizontal-{sm}"
    <li class="list-group-item">An item

    </li>

    <li class="list-group-item">A third item

    </li>
  </ul>. """
```

I'd appreciate it if an administrator somewhere could add bootstrap-5 as a tag.  The system doesn't trust me enough yet.

Answer (score 0):

I should have used:

```
<ul class="list-group list-group-horizontal justify-content-center" 
      style="list-style-type: none;">
      and. <li class="list-group-item-dk flex-fill-sm px-4">
```